# Backbone Edit View, destroy and re-display problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have the following Backbone.js view, and it works fine.  I have a DIV `id='edit-div'` and I render the view into it like so:

```
var BookView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        console.log('BookView created');
    },

    events: {
        "click a.rm": "rm_clicked",
        "click a.vi": "vi_clicked"
    },

        vi_clicked: function(e){
        var bv = new EditBookView({model: this.model, el: $(book_edit_el)});
        bv.render();
    },
```

Here is the view code:

```
var EditBookView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: Book,
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'edit-book',

    initialize: function(){
    console.log('Editing book view created');
    },

    events: {
        "click a.sed": "sed_clicked",
    },

    sed_clicked: function(e){
    var newval = $("#bookname").val();
    this.model.set('BookName', newval);
    this.model.save();
    this.remove();
    },

    render: function(){
    console.log('Rendering EditBookView');
    this.$el.append('<input id="bookname" type="text" value="' + this.model.get('BookName') + '"/><a class="sed" href="javascript:;">Save</a>');
    return this;
    }
});
```

Now, I click save, the `sed_clicked` method gets called and my book is updated via the REST service, no problem.

Problem is, my `edit-div` goes away and next time I click on an edit my edit view does not render because it has no container.  If I don't do remove, when I add another view the handler for the save click stays registered.  I can't find a good example to destroy the editor when I'm done with it but be able to create another one from the list I'm viewing.

Any ideas

Edited to say:

The pattern I'm looking for is pretty basic, I have a table view of a collection of models, with a delete link (working fine) and an edit link.  The edit link renders the selected element's inputs (again, working fine) and detects a save link click to update the model (working, too).  I can't figure out how to remove the form after the update and then display the next on that is clicked.

I wind up either removing the div I attach it to when remove() is called or I just hide() the code or replace it which does not unbind the event listener which calls the update 2 times the second time I edit an item, 3 times the third time, and so on.

Comment: Maybe setElement could help: http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `remove` call inside `sed_clicked`:

```
sed_clicked: function(e){
    var newval = $("#bookname").val();
    this.model.set('BookName', newval);
    this.model.save();
    this.remove(); // <--------------------------
}
```

You're giving that view an existing `el` when you create it:

```
var bv = new EditBookView({model: this.model, el: $(book_edit_el)});
// -------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) does:

> **remove** `view.remove()`
>
> Removes a view and its `el` from the DOM, and calls *stopListening* to remove any bound events that the view has *listenTo*'d.

So when you call `remove` on a view, it will remove its `el` from the DOM. You can also look at [the source](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.2.3/backbone.js#L1224) to see what's going on:

```
// Remove this view by taking the element out of the DOM, and removing any
// applicable Backbone.Events listeners.
remove: function() {
  this._removeElement();
  this.stopListening();
  return this;
},

// Remove this view's element from the document and all event listeners
// attached to it. Exposed for subclasses using an alternative DOM
// manipulation API.
_removeElement: function() {
  this.$el.remove();
},
```

The default `remove` implementation doesn't work that well when you're viewing is using an `el` that it doesn't create but you can provide your own `remove` to account for that:

```
remove: function() {
    this.undelegateEvents();
    this.$el.empty();
    this.stopListening();
    return this;
}
```

Calling [`empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) instead of [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) will remove the content of the `el` (including event handlers and such) while leaving the element intact, the [`undelegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-undelegateEvents) call will remove the event delegator that Backbone attaches to the view's `el`.

A better approach (IMO) is to not pass the `el` to the view; instead, let the view create its own `el` and let the caller place that `el` in a container somewhere. If you do this then the standard `remove` is sufficient and you'll have fewer problems with leaks and events.

Comment: Thank you!  I had figured out the remove part of it but I was missing the `stopListening()`, which is why I was getting the event fired 2 times for the second editor, 3 times for the third, etc...

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to fully understand your issue without seeing your HTML markup, however, it looks to me that the solution is to render the EditBookView into a container element within your BookView:

```
vi_clicked: function(e){
    var bv = new EditBookView({ model: this.model });
    this.$(book_edit_el).html(bv.render().$el);
},
```

Comment: But if `book_edit_el` is `#edit-div` then the `this.remove()` call in `sed_clicked` will remove it from the DOM.

Comment: Then use a different element.

Comment: My HTML consists of a table with a list rendered in it and a `<div id='edit-div'></div>` that starts as empty and gets the html rendered into it.  When I do editBookViewInstance.remove() the <div id='edit-div'> goes away so subsequent items do not render b/c there is no valid $el anymore.

Comment: See the other answer, the added remove method is what I needed.